# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 - Navigate To (Ctrl + comma) shortcut not using selected text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, pressing `Ctrl+comma` brings up the Navigate To window. Normally, it would use my selected text as input when I use the shortcut, but now it only uses something else.

I think it uses the last thing I copied to my clipboard that was from the first file I have open.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out as I was writing this question.

I had a Find prompt open on one of my open files (`Ctrl + F`). The Navigate To window was using this text rather than my selected text.

Closing the find prompt resumed normal behavior for the `Ctrl + comma` shortcut.